# Mysqli_query inside of a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I'm having trouble with a mysqli_query from inside a foreach loop, I'm getting a string from a table first, then separating that into an array. Then I try looping through the array and calling a query inside the loop.

```
$langs_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Languages FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($langs_result);

    $langs = $row['Languages'];
    $userLangs = str_replace(" ","",$langs);
    $userLangs = explode(",",$langs);
    print_r($userLangs);
    $posts = array();

    foreach($userLangs as $lang){
        echo "$lang <br>";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Language = '$lang'";
        $getLangPosts = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        array_push($posts, mysqli_fetch_assoc($getLangPosts));
    }

    print_r($posts);
```

for this user the langusges are German, Italian, Danish, and English, but the `$posts` array only contains the first post found from the first language (German), can anybody help? I am trying to get all of the posts for each language in the `$userLangs` array.

It's going through the `foreach` loop okay as the `$lang` variable that's echoed changes each time but the query still isn't working properly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use implode on $userLangs and change your query WHERE Language IN.. No need to hit the db multiple times,as to your issue,$getLangPosts is overwritten for each iteration

Comment: This is a very slow way of doing this. Join the tables and do just one lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
See this code:

```
<?php

$langs_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Languages FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($langs_result);

$langs = $row['Languages'];

// $langs = 'German, Italian, Danish, French'; added this to run the test

// $userLangs = str_replace(" ","",$langs); this is not needed, see the explode below
$userLangs = explode(", ",$langs);

foreach($userLangs as $lang){
    echo $lang;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Language = '$lang'";

    $getLangPosts = mysqli_query($con, $sql); // this is the result of the select *
    while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getLangPosts)){ // iterate over all the results
        $postField = $post["yourChoiceField..say..Title"]; // get something from each row
        array_push($posts, $title); // push into array
    }
}

print_r($posts);
```

Since the initial select is based on `username` I don't believe the first loop is needed so your code was on the right track.
A second loop was needed to iterate over the posts though and a field to populate the `$posts` array.

---

You need to perform `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in a loop

```
$langs_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Languages FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($langs_result)){

    $langs = $row['Languages'];

    $userLangs = str_replace(" ","",$langs); // i don't get why you are doing this though
    $userLangs = explode(",",$langs);
    print_r($userLangs);

    $posts = array();

    foreach($userLangs as $lang){
        echo "$lang <br>";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Language = '$lang'";
        $getLangPosts = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        array_push($posts, mysqli_fetch_assoc($getLangPosts));
    }

    print_r($posts);
}
```

It would help to know how what the `select` query actually returns.

Comment: I do the str replace and explode because the languages field in the user table is like `German, Italian, Danish, French`, so I wanted to get rid of the spaces tand then put in into an array to loop through

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this issue for ages :D

Answer (score 1):

```
select posts.* from posts
left join users on users.language=posts.language
where users.username='your_desiredusername'
group by users.language;
```

Just try to run this as a single query by filling the username
no need of multiple queries

Comment: does this take into account the fact that there are several languages in the user.languages field? :)

Comment: I tried `$sql = "select posts.* from posts
        left join users on users.Languages=posts.Language
        where users.username='$username'
        group by users.Language";

        $getLangPosts = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getLangPosts)){
              array_push($posts, $row1['Language']);
        }
        print_r($posts);`
and It returned `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

SORRY ABOUT THE FORMATTING

Comment: so , whats the result ? , did you got what you wanted

Comment: it returned the error message from the previous comment `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Comment: try echo $sql; and copy the string returned and try that string in your phpmyadmin , adn show me the result please...

Answer (score 1):

You an avoid multiple queries by doing a JOIN, using FIND_IN_SET to match on your comma separated list. You probably need to use REPLACE to get rid of the extra spaces in the comma separated list as well.

Then you can just loop around to display the data, displaying the language on change of language:-

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT a.Languages AS user_languages, 
                b.*
        FROM users a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN posts b
        ON FIND_IN_SET(b.Language, REPLACE(a.Languages, ' ', ''))
        WHERE a.Username = '$username'
        ORDER BY b.Languages";

$langs_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($langs_result))
{
    print_r(explode(', ', $row['user_languages']));
    $prev_langauge = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($langs_result))
    {
        if ($prev_langauge != $row['Languages'])
        {
            if ($prev_langauge != '')
            {
                print_r($posts);
            }
            $posts = array();
            echo $row['Languages']."<br>";
            $prev_langauge = $row['Languages'];
        }
        array_push($posts, mysqli_fetch_assoc($row));
    }
    if ($prev_langauge != '')
    {
        print_r($posts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the inner query to get the column data

```
foreach($userLangs as $lang){
        echo "$lang <br>";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Language = '$lang'";
        $getLangPosts = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getLangPosts))
              array_push($posts, $row1['YOUR_COLUMN_NAME']);
    }
```

OR you should use IN clause instead of loop

```
$langs_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Languages FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($langs_result)){

$langs = $row['Languages'];
$userLangs = str_replace(" ","",$langs);
$userLangs = explode(",",$langs);
print_r($userLangs);
$posts = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Language IN ('".implode(',',$userLangs)."')";
        $getLangPosts = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getLangPosts))
              array_push($posts, $row1['YOUR_COLUMN_NAME']);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now it's getting more than one post for German, but it's only getting the German ones. I think there's something to do with the query? Just a guess. Will try the IN clause :)

Comment: I gave the second solution a go and It doesn't throw and errors, but the array is empty when i try to `print_r` it :/

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` only fetches one row on each call you need to use it like this:

```
while ($row_new = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getLangPosts)){
   array_push($posts, $row_new);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is only adding the posts where the language is German to the array now, I don't know if it's something to do with the query? I've been confused about this for ages